# brunch build does not create directory and files

Tags: hapi.js, brunch

I am building a small hapijs app with brunch as asset management tool.

Running **brunch build** doesnt produce any compiled files.
My project structure is similar like the structure sample in
https://github.com/brunch/brunch/tree/stable/docs

brunch-config.coffee:

```
    exports.config =

        server:
            path: 'index.js'
            port: 8000
        paths:
            public: 'public'
        conventions:
            ignored: 'app/templates'
        files:
            javascripts:
                joinTo:
                    'js/app.js': /^app/
                    'js/vendor.js': /^vendor/

            stylesheets:
                defaultExtension: 'css'
                joinTo:'css/app.css': /^app/
```

**$brunch build -d** produces:

```
      brunch:watch Loaded plugins:  +0ms
      brunch:watch File 'app' received event 'addDir' +9ms
      brunch:watch File 'vendor' received event 'addDir' +20ms
      brunch:watch File 'package.json' received event 'add' +4ms
      brunch:watch File 'brunch-config.coffee' received event 'add' +0ms
      brunch:watch File 'app/assets' received event 'addDir' +5ms
      brunch:watch File 'app/templates' received event 'addDir' +1ms
      brunch:file-list Reading 'app/style.css' +2ms
      brunch:watch File 'app/style.css' received event 'add' +2ms
      brunch:watch File 'vendor/css' received event 'addDir' +0ms
      brunch:watch File 'vendor/scripts' received event 'addDir' +1ms
      brunch:watch File 'app/assets/images' received event 'addDir' +4ms
      brunch:file-list Reading 'app/templates/index.html' +1ms
      brunch:watch File 'app/templates/index.html' received event 'add' +0ms
      brunch:file-list Reading 'vendor/css/normalize.css' +0ms
      brunch:watch File 'vendor/css/normalize.css' received event 'add' +0ms
      brunch:file-list Reading 'vendor/css/skeleton.css' +0ms
      brunch:watch File 'vendor/css/skeleton.css' received event 'add' +0ms
'add' +1ms
      brunch:file-list Reading 'vendor/scripts/jquery-1.11.2.min.js' +0ms
      brunch:watch File 'vendor/scripts/jquery-1.11.2.min.js' received event 'add' +0ms
```

Do I miss something?
Thanks for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparantly I have to install *mandatory* plugin first such javascript-brunch and css-brunch( or any [style-language]-brunch plugin depending on your style language). 
This thing are subtle and it's not described explicitly in brunch docs. Had to reread and reread again of brunch guide https://github.com/brunch/brunch-guide/blob/master/content/en/chapter04-starting-from-scratch.md to get the 'aha' moment.

Comment: I think this is no longer true as of 2017 - those plugins have been deprecated